# What does mean by "out of a garage" ?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846/synopsis)

> He assigns Jordan to pitch a sale for a company called Aerotyne, a
>   small company **out of a garage** in Dubuque, Iowa

What does mean by "out of a garage" ?

Comment: "The content of this page was created directly by users and has not been screened or verified by IMDb staff." Many of these movie summaries are likely not well written and quite possibly not grammatically sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quite large companies (for example [Hewlett Packard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewlett-Packard)) started out as a couple of guys  working in their parent's garage.

A company that is running **out of a garage** is a metaphor for a company that is still at a very early stage in its development.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what came to my mind was literal. Here, I understood "out of" to mean "from". So I took it to mean that the people who run the company run it **from** their garage. It is common for small, start-up businesses to [run out of garages](http://isbdc.org/starting-a-garage-based-business/) at the beginning.

[image]

I took a look at the movie and this is what the guy said:

> They're just a couple of brothers that are making radar detector 
>   out of their garage. They're out of Dubuque. Maybe it's microwaves. I'm not sure,
>   but you call the company [on] the main line. Their mom, Dorthy, 
>   answers and she is so sweet.

So it seems like this business is literally running out of the brothers' garage.